# How to define key store in SOAPUI

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

How to define key store in SoapUI it is giving error invalid keystore format. Which file i to define for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I use a .pfx file.  On the SSL tab, I enter the path to the .pfx and the password.  Then it "just works".

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a problem with v4.5, as some users (including a co-worker) are getting "invalid keystore format", with keystores that worked previously. See this link:
http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13181&p=33196&hilit=p12#p33196

I had a different error with 4.5, so I'm back to 4.0 which is working fine for me.  Perhaps  your issue will go away if you use 4.0 instead.